# Call js function every time DjangoForm is loaded?

Tags: django, django-forms, onload, form-fields

I have next form:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
     model = ExampleModel
     fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
     widgets = {'field1': forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'onchangeJsFunction()'})}
```

So far i have been able to add onchange property to my select field that calls 'onchangeJsFunction()' every time 'field1' value is changed. My next goal is to add a function that is going to be executed every time form is loaded, and i am not sure how to do it. I have tried adding onload property to a input field this way:

```
...
widgets = {'field_2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'onload': 'onloadJsFunction();'})}
...
```

but it does not give any results so far.

How am i supposed to execute certain JS function every time my Django Form is loaded?

Comment: Can't you add it to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: If i add it to my body tag, the function is going to be called only once - when the page is loaded. The thing is that my form is within hidden bootsrap modal window, and that modal window, with form, shows when certain button is pressed on webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment that you are using a bootstrap modal - you could add an event listener to the modal that runs code when it is is shown

In bootstrap 4 (jquery)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 //onloadJsFunction() or similar
})
```

in bootstrap 5

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal')

myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  ////onloadJsFunction() or similar
})
```

(tweaked from bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/))